# Как сделать один раз обновление страницы?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы автоматически один раз обновилась страница? Без клика на кнопку и т.п.

Comment: Ну здесь надо пробовать хранить информацию об обновлении страницы в кукисах

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Можно тоже самое с использованием php cookie и

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh'; content='TIME; url=URL'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Привет. Можно попробовать реализовать это с помощью JavaScript'а и с использованием Cookie. Примерно так должно работать:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    function setCookie (name, value)
    {
        document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value);
    }

    function getCookie(name)
    {
        var cookie = " " + document.cookie;
        var search = " " + name + "=";
        var setStr = null;
        var offset = 0;
        var end = 0;
        if (cookie.length > 0)
        {
            offset = cookie.indexOf(search);
            if (offset != -1)
            {
                offset += search.length;
                end = cookie.indexOf(";", offset)
                if (end == -1)
                {
                    end = cookie.length;
                }
                setStr = unescape(cookie.substring(offset, end));
            }
        }
        return(setStr);
    }

    var cookie = getCookie('reload');

    if (cookie == null)
    {
        setCookie('reload', 0);
    }

    var reload = getCookie('reload');

    if (reload == 0)
    {
        setCookie('reload', 1);
        // обновляем страницу
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Так работает.

Comment: alert никогда не будет показан